# What's the best way to search a DB table using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I want to know what's the best way to search a DB table using a stored procedure (let's say text search)?

What are the points I should look at?

Let me know if you guys want more information.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server.

Comment: A few more details on what you mean by "search a DB table" would be useful.  Do you want to search for tables in a database, search for fields in a table, search the contents of a single table, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you list of tables whose name matches to your keyword

SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U' AND name LIKE '%keyword%'